# Get validation error list of form control in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using angular 6 with reactive forms. I want to show validation messages dynamically. And I wrote some code like below. But I take this error: **Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays**. How can I take list of errors of input?

**.html file**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="studentName">

    <div *ngFor="let err of myForm.controls.studentName.errors">
      <div>You entered not valid input</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**.ts file**

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  studentName: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. My mistake is, I thought that `myForm.controls.studentName.errors` is an array. But, it is not array, it's an object. So, below code working perfectly.

**.html file**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="studentName">

    <div *ngFor="let err of getErrorList(myForm.controls.studentName.errors)">
      <div>You entered not valid input</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**.ts file**

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  studentName: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]
});

getErrorList(errorObject) {
  return Object.keys(errorObject);
}
```

Comment: It gets console errors if the object is null.

```
public getErrorList(errorObject) {
    console.log("errorObject: ", errorObject);
    if (errorObject === null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return Object.keys(errorObject);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your errors separately. You cannot use *ngFor here.
You can do something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="myForm.get('studentName').invalid && (myForm.get('studentName').dirty || myForm.get('studentName').touched)">


    <div *ngIf="myForm.get('studentName').hasError('required')">
      You entered not valid input.
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="myForm.get('studentName').hasError('minlength')">
      Name must be at least 3 characters long.
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jocactus. But, I don't want write `<div>` for every error. I want write only one div and then I set message from generic .ts file.